# How to Interpret decl-specifier in the C++ Grammar

Tags: c++, parsing, visual-c++, grammar, parser-generator

I copied the full c++ grammar into my parser generator but is having problems parsing C++ declaration. How should we interpret a **decl-specifier** when parsing a pointer type declaration like **char* varname**?

Using MSDN's c++ grammar as an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aah9xbf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx:

A specifier is like that:

```
decl-specifiers :
    decl-specifiersopt decl-specifier
decl-specifier :
    storage-class-specifier
    type-specifier
    fct-specifier
    friend
    typedef
    __declspec ( extended-decl-modifier-seq )
```

Acccording to that msdn's description **char *lpszAppName;** should have a decl-specifier = **"char * "**, name = "**lpszAppName**".  But my test run shows that the decl-specifier should be **char**, the declarator (i.e. name) should be **" * lpszAppName"** . Note that the asterisk precedes the name - NOT FOLLOWING the type keyword char.  This test result seems reasonable as under decl-specifier, I cannot find anything defining a pointer i.e. there is no rule under the **decl-speciifer** that can lead to a **ptr-operator**.

I tested with ANTLR4 parser generator with the full c++ grammar copied from the specification to parse this:

```
char * 
testfunction(int *cx)
{
  return;
}
```

The resultant parse tree is like this:

[image: parse tree]

Clearly  a return type "char *" is actually parsed as return type "char" i.e. a node under the decl-specifier, while the * is associated with the function name i.e. a node under the declarator.  The (int* cx ) parameter declaration is also considered type "int" while the pointer * is a node under the declarator for cx.

Is my test correct?  If yes, then what should be the grammar looks like if we have to support Visual C++ specific function modifier keywords like __cdecl, __stdcall, or __fastcall e.g.

```
char * __fastcall
testfunction(int *cx)
{
  return;
}
```

Clearly, the syntax requires the "char*" be really treated as a type i.e. a node under abstract-declarator.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the famous `char* x, y;` declaration. `y` is a `char`, not a `char*`. The reason is that the `*` applies to `x` only. The `decl-specifier` indeed is just `char`.

Comment: How to upgrade the grammar to support VC++'s char * __fastcall function() {...} syntax. I'm working on a tool that has to understand VC++.

Comment: It's in the Microsoft grammar: `init-declarator: ms-modifier-list[opt] declarator initializer[opt]`, `__fastcall` is a `ms-modifier`.

Comment: Thx MSalters, and no, the Microsoft grammar in MSDN (for VC++2003.net only) cannot parse my example (my only explanation is typo in MSDN). The grammar can only parse "char *__fastcall js::functinName() {..}. Note the qualified id is requried. And the grammar you quoted (init-declarator: ...) can only parse "char __fastcall * function() {...}". Note the * is to the right of the ms-modifier-list since ptr-operator is part of the declarator.